# Publish app without verifying bank account

Tags: android

I recently set up a merchant account for getting revenues from a paid app I developed. However, I got the message below.

> Recently, you specified a new bank account to receive your payouts.
>   However, before you can be eligible to receive any payouts, you must
>   verify your bank account information.

Now the verification process takes a long time because Google first deposits an amount into the specified account, etc. My question is- can I release my paid app, without verifying the bank account, or should I wait? I cannot find the answer to this question anywhere online, and what better place than SO. Thanks!

Comment: as far as I know you cannot(shouldnt?) release it since then Google wouldnt know where to deposit the money that you will be receiving for that paid app because it hasnt verified the bank account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Google can't just assume that your bank account is going to be verified... what would they do if it never got verified and they had already put your app was on the market?

Comment: thanks alex. i guess i'll have to wait another week then- 2 days for google to make a transfer to my account and another 3 days for the amount to show up on my statement.